# How can I reduce the number of calls to a MongoDB instance when using a role-based application?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm specifically talking about NodeJS with MongoDB (I know MongoDB is schema-less, but let's be realistic about the importance of structuring data for a moment).

Is there some magic solution to minimising the number of queries to a database in regards to authenticating users? For example, if the business logic of my application needs to ensure that a user has the necessary privileges to update/retrieve data from a certain Document or Collection, is there any way of doing this without two calls to the database? One to check the user has the rights, and the other to retrieve the necessary data?

**EDIT:**

Another question closed by the trigger-happy SO moderators. I agree the question is abstract, but I don't see how it is "not a real question". To put it simply:

What is the best way to reduce the number of calls to a database in role-based applications, specifically in the context of NodeJS + MongoDB? Can it be done? Or is role-based access control for NodeJS + MongoDB inefficient and clumsy?

Comment: Of course there's no "magic solution." There never is.

Comment: Indeed, but I don't understand the close votes. I believe there is an answer that can be used elsewhere. See my attenpt at one below.

Comment: @shennan, make your title shorter, it will help your question. You are off to a good start with "How can I reduce the number of calls to a monge database in a role-based application"

Answer (score 2):

Obviously, you know wich document holds which rigths. I would guess that it is a field in the document, like :

```
{ 'foo':'bar'
  'canRead':'sales' }
```

At the start of the session you could query the roles a user has. Say

```
{ 'user':'shennan',
  'roles':[ 'users','west coast','sales'] }
```

You could store that list of roles in the user's session. With that in hand, all that's left to do is add the roles with an `$in` operator, like this :

```
db.test.find({'canRead':{'$in':['users','west coast','sales']})
```

Where the value for the `$in` operator is taken from the user's session. Here is code to try it out on your own, in the mongo console :

```
db.test.insert(  { 'foo':'bar', 'canRead':'sales' })
db.test.insert(  { 'foo2':'bar2', 'canRead':['hr','sales'] })
db.test.insert(  { 'foo3':'bar3', 'canRead':'hr' })

> db.test.find({}, {_id:0})
{ "foo" : "bar", "canRead" : "sales" }
{ "foo2" : "bar2", "canRead" : [  "hr",  "sales" ] }
{ "foo3" : "bar3", "canRead" : "hr" }
```

Document with 'foo3' can't be read by someone in sales :

```
> db.test.find({'canRead':{'$in':['users','west coast','sales']}}, {_id:0})
{ "foo" : "bar", "canRead" : "sales" }
{ "foo2" : "bar2", "canRead" : [  "hr",  "sales" ] }
```

Comment: I would say this is quite bad RBAC/RBAM schema, if you wish to add a new role to items you must update ALL detail items

Comment: @Sammaye could you clarify why this would be a bad role-based access? Also, I take it there is no way to write to the document within the same call as determining if the document is writable. In your example, I would have to initiate two calls: one to determine that the user can write/update, and another to actually perform a write/update. Obviously I'm just getting started with MongoDB, so I've not fine-toothed the API yet.

Comment: @shennan Indeed not, this is atomic it is true but the requirement to keep it maintained is just too costly, I mean imagine updating a million items with roles attached, that just wuld not be feasible, this is why RBAC/RBAM system are implemented quite differently so that multiple queries are required.

Comment: @Sammaye so are you saying that RBAC/RBAM cannot be achieved gracefully with MongoDB?

Comment: @shennan It is a troublesome area, but to be honest, where SQL would JOIN MongoDB would do multiple queries, that is what MongoDB is designed to do so by trying to shove it all into one query you are actually trying to go against what MongoDB is all about

Comment: @Sammaye I see. So I should have more faith in MongoDB's ability to be hammered with multiple queries, or I should give up on RBAC all-together? The reason behind this thread is down to security concerns that, if a user/lower-level administrator was granted read/write access to everything in my MongoDB instance, then the data could be scrutinised by attackers. It's really a migration issue from MySQL. Am I having trouble delegating the rules of database authentication to my application logic? It's possible that's what it is.

Comment: @shennan I would put your faith in sending more queries to MongoDB, they specifically are designed to do joins etc from the client side and the db is optimised for multiple round trips. I would say you are just having problems delegating the application logic, if you implements the right rules in the application itself, in the action/controller then nothing bad can happen

Comment: The thing that bothers me with my answer is that it is 100% homebrew. It will be harder to test and for some auditor to validate, if need be, compoare to an enterprise Java application with the RBAC built-in.   Bugs can be everywhere, but there is expertise and tools out there to help you out.

Comment: As for updating documents : updating millions of documents take a while, that's true, more if you indexed the role attributs wich is likely. But it is a single mongo request. I will add that to my answer (over the weekend) to show how it could be done.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely do-able, but w/o more context it's hard to determine what's best.

One simple solution that comes to mind is to cache users and their permissions in memory so no DB lookup is required. At this point you can just issue the query for documents where permission match and...

Let me know if you need a few more ideas.